# create an interface with base classes while derived classes contain their own implementation

Tags: c#, polymorphism

This is my code

```
class InternalDevice1
{
}

class InternalDevice2
{
}

class SpecificDevice1 : InternalDevice1
{
}

class SpecificDevice2 : InternalDevice2
{
}

class SpecificDevice3 : InternalDevice1
{
}

class SpecificDevice4 : InternalDevice2
{
}

class MyWholeDevice1 : IDevice
{
   MyWholeDevice(SpecificDevice1 device1, SpecificDevice2 device2) { }
   SpecificDevice1 Device { get; }   
}

class MyWholeDevice2 : IDevice
{
   MyWholeDevice(SpecificDevice3 device1, SpecificDevice4 device2) { }
   SpecificDevice3 Device { get; }  
}


interface IDevice
{
   InternalDevice1 Device { get; }
}
```

The problem is that the return type in IDevice is InternalDevice1 (which is more general)
while I need the SpecificDevice (which is still dervied from InternalDevice)
I'm encountering a problem when trying to use this:

```
IDevice = new MyWholeDevice ...
```

Comment: If I understand you right, its a derived type. So, cast the return type to SpecificDevice

Answer (score 0):

You should make your IDevice `generic`

```
interface IDevice<TDevice>
   where TDevice : InternalDevice1
{
   TDevice Device { get; }
}
```

Then your classes will look like this:

```
class MyWholeDevice1 : IDevice<SpecificDevice1>
{
   MyWholeDevice(SpecificDevice1 device1, SpecificDevice2 device2) { }
   SpecificDevice1 Device { get; }   
}

class MyWholeDevice2 : IDevice<SpecificDevice3>
{
   MyWholeDevice(SpecificDevice3 device1, SpecificDevice4 device2) { }
   SpecificDevice3 Device { get; }  
}
```

Comment: OK, thats actually what I did, so looks I'm in the right direction
the problem then occurred when I tried the following

IDevice<InternalDevice1> = (IDevice<InternalDevice1>) new MyWholeDevice(new SpecificDevice1, ...)

I get a runtime error: unable to cast object MyWholeDevice to type IDevice

Comment: @GeorgeRubin and `MyWholeDevice` is what? Such class isn't defined in your code.